# add a title to excel file when i use grid control export from devexpress in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I'm using a gridcontrol from devexpress.I want to export data using grid.ExportToXls.
How can I add a title to the first line and a footer to the Excel generated file ?

Answer (score 0):

Iam sure this will be helpfull for you :-)

http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q287367